# Laravel 8 with PHP 8.1.10 at Windows Server 2016

Tags: php, laravel, windows, server, windows-server

I have simple project and program with laravel 8 and PHP 8.1.10
i put project and program at pc (windows 11, 16gb), this pc like server
so poeple can access with IP and no problem. Fast reload and fast access menu

But...
When i move project to Real Server with Windows Server 2016 Standart, every time when click menu and reload page. So very long, 4-7 second time. I give 32gb ram, 64bit, 32 core processor, 900Mbps(90MB) internet.
So..i move again to normal pc, has no problem..fast reload and fast access menu.

Can someone help to explain me, thanks you

*sorry and very sorry for my english so bad

maybe someone can explain to me, its problem at windows server or what ?

Comment: We can't tell for sure. There are many reasons for this behavior: could be some firewall policies slowing down access, a networking issue, or maybe some problem related to database access, etc ...
I don't think that the problem is resources limitation, because 16GB RAM for a server is more than sufficient in majority of cases.